# No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist'

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, aspectj

While doing insert operation on my web service which is deployed on Tomcat I am facing following exception

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with
>   actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably
>   process 'persist' call

My spring-jpa.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- ========================= RESOURCE DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

    <!-- Activates a load-time weaver for the context. Any bean within the context that implements LoadTimeWeaverAware 
        (such as LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) will receive a reference to the autodetected load-time weaver. -->



    <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatLoadTimeWeaver" />



    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryReadOnly" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ReadOnlyBasePersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryReadWrite" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ReadWriteBasePersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <bean id="transactionManagerReadOnly" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryReadOnly" />
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="90" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerReadWrite" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryReadWrite" />
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="90" />
    </bean>


    <!-- ========================= BUSINESS OBJECT DEFINITIONS ========================= -->

    <!-- Instruct Spring to perform declarative transaction management automatically on annotated classes. -->
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadWrite"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadOnly"/>

    <!-- Post-processor to perform exception translation on @Repository classes (from native exceptions such 
         as JPA PersistenceExceptions to Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy). -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

dependecncies.gradle is as follows

```
    compile (
        'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.2',
        'javax.xml:jsr173:1.0',
        'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1',
        'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5',
        'regexp:regexp:1.3',
        'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4',
        'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4',
        'org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-jms:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:4.0.9.RELEASE'
        'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2',
        'org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.2' 
}
```

Service class is as follows

```
class Facade impelments Ifacade {
@Autowired
private MyDao dao

@Override
@Transactional
public CreateRequestResponse createRequests(List<BusinnessObject> bobject) {
          this.dao.createRequests(bobject)
} 

}
```

My persistence.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="ReadOnlyBasePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/DS_RW</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.temp.request.model.dataobject.RqstOne</class>
        <class>com.temp.request.model.dataobject.RqstTwo</class>
        <class>com.temp.request.model.dataobject.RqstThree</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="com.temp.request.tomcat.TomcatPlatform"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="ReadWriteBasePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/DS_RW</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>com.temp.request.model.dataobject.RqstOne</class>
        <class>com.temp.request.model.dataobject.RqstTwo</class>
        <class>com.temp.request.model.dataobject.RqstThree</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="com.temp.request.tomcat.TomcatPlatform"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle11Platform" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: You can only have a single `<tx:annotation-driven />` the other tx manager needs to be selected by specifiying it in the `@Transactional` in the corresponding method. Also you are mixing jars from different versions of Spring, that is trouble waiting to happen, you are mixing 4.0.9 and 5.0.0. Tomcat instrumentation is now in `spring-context`.

Comment: why only one <tx:annotation-driven /> ?

Comment: Because there can only be a single main transaction manager. Currently that is your readonly only (the last one is the one that remains).

Comment: How to handle two transaction managers?

Comment: Have you read my initial comment? --> **the other tx manager needs to be selected by specifiying it on the @Transactional in the corresponding method.**.

Comment: this is working fine on weblogic and it is giving problem after deploying on tomcat

Comment: Then it works by luck (if this is the same configuration used on weblogic, which I doubt due to how the load time weaver is configured). Regardless of that you can have only a single tx:annotation-driven, 2 won't work.

Comment: for weblogic only this line is different in file <context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver" />

Comment: and as stated as well you are mxing versions of srping especially the instrumentation... Fix your dependencies first.

Comment: should I add spring-context:5.0 instead of  spring-instrument-tomcat:4.0.9 ?

Comment: You already have `spring-context` as it is a dependency of multiple of your other `spring-*` dependencies.

Comment: So in simple language I need to remove spring-instrument-tomcat:4.0.9 dependency

Comment: for starters, and you should really have a single tx element and the others should be in the `@Transactional` (that is also explained in the reference guide). This might work on Weblogic due to the use of a JTA based transaction manager instead of a local one.

Comment: updated persistence.xml in question kindly check

Comment: Without knowing what changed this adds nothing. This one seems targeted for tomcat not weblogic.

Comment: @M.Deinum spring-instrument is part of spring-context

Comment: @M.Deinum spring-instrument-tomcat is not part of spring-context

Comment: Yes it does (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/5.0.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/tomcat).

Comment: @M.Deinum when I remove mode=aspectj in  <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManagerReadWrite"/>  my application is not giving exception